# Monochrome image resize, goes to grayscale?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, monochrome

There is a pretty easy image which I want to behave monochrome:

[image]

You can see on the left, and also on top there is one thin line which seems semi-transparent.

I dropped the colors by selecting *Image > Mode > Grayscale*, then selecting *Image > Mode > Duotone (with only black as tint)*.

(I'm not sure this is the right way to my goal)

So, there are those semi-transparent sides, but okay, I don't care, because if I drop a background behind it they are gone:

[image]

However, how can I limit the colors to be really duo? I.e. only full black, and full white (and maybe 100% transparent as third)?

Back to my image: I want to reduce the size: *Image > Image size (with Automatic resample)*:

Now even with the background:

[image]

And also without the background:

[image]

I got a massive undeniable semi-transparency at the sides. Now it's not hidden by adding a solid background underneath.

So: my goal is to have an image with only Black and White (no intermittent shades), with optionally a 100% transparency. This way I will be able to resize the image without those annoying transparency effects on the sides (I guess/hope).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Black and white is traditionally **not** a duotone. It's **one color** - black. White is really never seen as a color. On a press white doesn't exist, except in very special circumstances. If you want white pixels for screen display as well as transparency, then you sort of *have* to use Greyscale mode.

Duotone is **not** necessary and is of no benefit here. Duotones restrict the *number of colors*, but do **not** restrict tints (%) of those colors. Greyscale is the best you can do.

If you want **only** black and white pixels in a raster image then "Bitmap" is the proper mode in Photoshop... convert to greyscale, (cuz ya have to) then to Bitmap. **However**, this will **not** allow transparency. In Bitmap mode, white is seen as being transparent. So, again, Greyscale is the best you can do if you need black, white, *and* transparent pixels.

When resizing, to prevent the introduction of grey pixels caused by anti-aliasing, you will want to use the `Nearest Neighbor` interpolation method.

This prevents the introduction of partial opacity pixels (% of colors) which are used to "smooth" edges (anti-alias) and ensures all pixels are solid. In your use description, it would keep all pixels either black, white, or transparent - no greys.

[image]

With transform handles active, the interpolation method is in the **Control Bar** across the top of the screen...

[image]

Comparison....

[image]

Comment: Amazingly well described. Thank you!